# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, redhat, centos-7

I am running `postgresql-9.6` on `Rhel7`. I know that the default/root user doesnt have a password, however i will like to use `phpPgAdmin` to do my work. the problem is I have edited my `pg_hba.conf` file to look as follow, (based on various documentation I have read so far:

```
local   all             all                          password
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all       127.0.0.1/32       password
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128      ident
```

The only problem is that after this configuration even the default user `postgres` has lost access completely. When I try to log in as the root user with `psql` and and enter `my computer's root user's password` this is what what happens:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

but when I change the above configuration on the `pg_hba.conf` file to:

```
peer
ident
ident
```

I can log in as root however `phpPgAdmin` won't let me in without a password.

Comment: If you're using **Docker**. Try to check if your local DB is active because mostly it's conflicting with Docker, if so, you can deactivate it or uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

I was in same situation. after installation on window machine I was getting below error:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx>psql -U postgres

psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/pgpass
.conf"
```

To fix the above, I edited 'pgpass.conf' file with password I was using for the 'postgres' database, and it worked.

Comment: I can't find this file it in pgsql 12 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

This error can provide from the fact that you installed actively another version of Postgres or passively within a system update (and you may not be aware in this case).

The consequence is that you try to connect to the current version of database that has changed (since install or update) and having in fact a port number that has changed. Therefore you may need to check this port number :

```
isogladiator@edubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status
9.3/main (port **5432**): online
9.5/main (port **5434**): online
11/main (port **5433**): online
```

You may be using standard port 5432 while it has become 5433 for example.